# How to use forEach to generate a concatenated string

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript to build a table.
This is the part of the code, but is not so important.

```
template: function(row) {
   return '<span class="kt-badge kt-badge-- kt-badge--dot"></span>&nbsp;<span class="kt-font-bold kt-font-' + row.name + '">' + row.title + '</span>';
}
```

In this case row is a single element, I can do that.

I have a situation where `row` is an array of elements, so I must return the template concatenated with the data of every element of the array.

```
template: function(row) {
   let string;
   function createElement(item,string) {
     string.concat('<span class="kt-badge kt-badge--inline kt-badge--pill">' + item[row.Status].title + '</span>');
     }
  row.sections.forEach(createElement);
  return string
  }
```

It doesn't work. I know that there is something wrong, but I want to know if is there an easier way to do this. Basically I need to loop on the row elements when raw is an array and create my html snippet.

Comment: concat doesn't modify your string but returns a new string

Comment: let string = '';
row.sections.forEach(item => string+='<span class="kt-badge kt-badge--inline kt-badge--pill">' + item[row.Status].title + '</span>')

Comment: I wouldn't use the same name for the local variable and the scoped variable. Maybe use string and str.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `map` to convert each element in `row.sections` to the element string, then `join` the array of strings together.

```
template: function(row) {
    return row.sections.map((item) => {
        return '<span class="kt-badge kt-badge--inline kt-badge--pill">' + item[row.Status].title + '</span>\n';
    }).join(' ')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have an array and need to *reduce* it to a single value... then [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is your tool.

```
template: function(row) {
    return row.sections.reduce((c, item) => c += `<span class="…">${item[row.Status].title}</span>`, '');
}
```